# Monotonic subsequences and convergence

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

$\{x_n\}$ is a sequence such that every monotonic subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ converges to the limit $x$. 
Prove that: $x_n\rightarrow x$.

Comment: *To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far*. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, many would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Prove..."), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: Do you know that every sequence of reals has a monotone subsequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $x_n$ does not converge to $x$. Then there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that for every $k$ 
$$|x_{n_k}-x|>\epsilon$$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Since every sequence of real numbers has a monotonic subsequence, we can pick a monotonic subsequence $x_{n_{k_l}}$.

And here we encounter a contraduction: $x_{n_{k_l}}$ is a monotonic subsequence of $x_n$ so it converges to $x$, and yet on the other hand it is a subsequence of $x_{n_k}$ and hence cannot converge to $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Choose a subsequence converging to $\limsup x_n$, by dropping terms you can assume that it is monotonic, so $\limsup x_n = x$. Similarly $\liminf x_n = x$. Therefore the limit of $x_n$ exists and $\lim x_n = x$.