# Use monotonic property of subsequences to prove one sided limits at a point of a monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

We were given a two parter homework question:

1. Prove that if every subsequence of a sequence $x_n$ is converging to L then $x_n$ converges to L.
2. Use what you proved above to prove that if $f(x)$ is a monotonic increasing function at $(a,b)$ then $\forall x_0 \in (a,b):$

$i. \lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x) = inf_{x>x_0} f(x) $

$ii. \lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x) = sup_{x<x_0} f(x) $

$iii. \lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x) \le f(x_0) \le \lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x) $

Now part 1. was easy to prove (used something similiar to [Monotonic subsequences and convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264992/monotonic-subsequences-and-convergence))

As for part 2, I had no idea how to use the first part in my proof. What I attempted was take a series $x_n$ of increasing values whose limit is $x_0$, therefore the series of $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$ (from the monotonic property of $f(x)$), now since this series is monotonic and bounded it converges to it's supremum, same for the series of $x_0$ and $f(x_0)$ values from the right of $x_0$ (only this time they are decreasing).

Still not sure how to prove $iii$ but in my proof I haven't used the property I proved at part 1, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot conclude that $f(x_n)\to f(x_0)$ from $x_n\to x_0$ just using monotonicity--you need continuity, as well.

Instead, note that for all $x>x_0$ with $x\in(a,b),$ we have $f(x)>f(x_0).$ Since $x_0\in(a,b),$ there exists some $x\in(a,b)$ with $x>x_0,$ and so $\{f(x):x\in(a,b),x>x_0\}$ is a non-empty set of reals that is bounded below by $f(x_0),$ so has a greatest lower bound. Put $y_0=\inf_{x>x_0}f(x).$ Now suppose that $x_n\searrow x_0$ ($x_n$ converges monotonically to $x_0$ from above). We know that $f(x_{n+1})<f(x_n)$ for all $n$ since $f$ is monotone increasing and $x_{n+1}<x_n$ for all $n,$ so $\bigl\{f(x_n)\bigr\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a monotone decreasing sequence. Moreover, by definition of $y_0,$ we have that $f(x_n)\ge y_0$ for all $n,$ meaning that $\bigl\{f(x_n)\bigr\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded below by $y_0$, and so $f(x_n)\searrow y$ for some $y\ge y_0$.

Now, if we had $y>y_0,$ then by definition of infimum, there would be some $x\in(a,b)$ with $x>x_0$ such that $f(x)<y.$ Since $x\in(a,b)$ with $x>x_0$ and since $x_n\searrow x_0,$ then we know that $x>x_n>x_0$ for all but finitely many $n$. But then $f(x_n)<f(x)<y$ for all but finitely-many $n,$ which is impossible, since $f(x_n)\searrow y.$ Therefore, we must have $y\le y_0,$ and so $y=y_0.$ Thus, for all sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of points of $(a,b)$ with $x_n\searrow x_0,$ we have that $f(x_n)\searrow y_0=\inf_{x>x_0}f(x).$ Thus, $$\lim_{x\searrow x_0}f(x)=\inf_{x>x_0}f(x),$$ as desired.

Similar arguments can be used for 2(ii). Part (iii) is all about monotonicity of $f.$

P.S.: Part 1 can be done even more easily when you observe that $y_n=x_{n+1}$ gives a subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty.$

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, wish I could upvote your answer. Though, while your answer is obviously more formal and coherent than mine (and obviously correct where mine was missing some key observations) I still can't grasp where is the first part incorporated (as we were asked to do) in a proof such as yours or mine. They both could have worked without it and we were asked to build upon it in our proof of part 2.

Comment: To be honest, I do think the first part is useful for the second in any way. It's also worth noting that I left out some of the explanations in my proof sketch, so be sure you (know how to) justify each step.