# Question on finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $f_\mu(x) =\mu((-\infty,x])$. Show that $f_\mu$ is monotone increasing, $\mu((a,b])=f_{\mu}(b)-f_\mu(a) $ for all $a<b$, $f_\mu$ is right continuous and $f_\mu(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$. 
Also show there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between the class of finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$ and the class of bounded,increasing right continuous functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $f_\mu(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$.

My attempt:

1) For $a<b$, $f_\mu$ we have that $f_\mu(b)=\mu((-\infty,b])=\mu((-\infty,a]\cup(a,b])=\mu((a,b])+f_\mu(a)$, thus $f_\mu(a)\leq f_\mu(b)$ so $f_\mu$ increasing.

2)$\mu((a,b])=f_{\mu}(b)-f_\mu(a) $ proved same way.

3)To show that $f_\mu(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ we take a sequence $x_n$ going to $-\infty$. I can always find a subsequence that will converge monotonically say $x_{n_k}$ and then $\mu((-\infty,x_{n_k}]) \rightarrow 0$ from the fact that we have decreasing sets. But how can I use that to prove that $\mu((-\infty,x_{n}]) \rightarrow 0$? Also the same question translates to the right continuous case.

Thank you for your help guys. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264992/monotonic-subsequences-and-convergence

Comment: If $A_n$ is a decreasing collection of sets and $\mu A_1$ is finite (which must be true here) then $\mu(\cap_n A_n) = \lim_n \mu A_n$. Since $\cap_n(-\infty, x_n] = \emptyset$, you have the desired result.